# Session flush is not working in magento for memcache

Tags: magento, session, memcached

I have successfully configured `memcache` session for `magento` and it's working fine. Now i want to flush memcache session from the magento itself by using the memcache object.
I have tried

```
$memcache = new Memcache();
$memcache->flush();
$memcache->flush_all();
$memcache->delete(arguments);
```

But from above nothing is working for me.

I am able to flush all session from the command line but can't do it from script. Here i am using `ubuntu` as a OS.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->flush();
```

It cleans cache storage, including memcached data. I'm using memcache and here is my shell script to clean cache data:

```
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

require '../app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('admin')->setUseSessionInUrl(false);
Mage::getConfig()->init();

try {
    Mage::app()->cleanCache(); // Clean Magento caches
    Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->flush(); // Clean cache storage

    echo "\033[01;31m Cache instances were flushed successfully \033[0m \n";
    flush();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "\nAn error was occurred: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    flush();
}
```

It's cleaning memcache storage. Memcache by default use one storage for cache and sessions. If you want remove all data from current memcached session use class (or or some child) Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien. There is a method unsetAll which removes all data from the session. The method also cleans memcached session if any.

Comment: Hi, It's working fine for clearing cache. but i actually wants to clear the session.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the method which will help you to clean session data.